# Exit Function Not Working - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to exit the function if either the value is equal to the value I'm looking for, or if the row is equal to the row I'm looking for.

But every time I use `Exit Function`, it doesn't work. And if I replace it with `End Function` it tells me that I don't have an End to my If statement. And I'm getting lost.

```
Function recursion(whereItEnds As Integer, lookingFor As Variant, currentMarker As Range, I As Integer, wsEverything As Worksheet) As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim newMarker As String
    newMarker = currentMarker.Value
    Dim currentMarker1 As Range
    recursion = 2
    col = 2
    If (StrComp(lookingFor, newMarker, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    While (IsEmpty(wsEverything.Cells(col, "B").Value) = False)
        If (StrComp(wsEverything.Cells(col, "B").Value, newMarker, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            wsEverything.Cells.Range("A" & col, "F" & col).Copy
            Worksheets("Review").Cells.Range("A" & I).PasteSpecial
            Worksheets("Review").Cells.Range("G" & I).Value = col
            I = I + 1
            Set currentMarker1 = wsEverything.Cells(col, "E")

            If (col = whereItEnds) Then
                Exit Function
            End If
            recursion = recursion(whereItEnds, lookingFor, currentMarker1, I, wsEverything)
        End If
        col = col + 1
    Wend
End Function
```

I'm almost completely out of ideas as to why neither works.

EDIT: It hits the if statements, it goes into those codes. but when debugging, it touches "exit function" but then it just keeps going. i just want it to end the statement. This is pulling data off another long sheet and putting it on a second sheet. it is checking for child parent circular errors. where a parent in the future is dependent on the child that originally was dependent on it.

Comment: Can you provide the data that you say it's not working with? Exit function should work

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SOP4Q

Comment: I'm still kind of lost, I don't see how the function should behave and why is not behaving as expected. Can you try editing the question with just one line? Ex: "This is what I have ... and  this is what I expect ..." sort of guidance?

Comment: Try replacing `Exit Function` line of code with `goto here` , then put `here:` before `End Function` line of code.

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a very good description.  What happens?  Does it crash?  Does it execute the statement but not Exit?  Does your code even execute the `Exit Function` statement - i.e. when single-stepping through the code does it ever get to the line?  If it doesn't get to it, check the variables in the `If` statements and see whether you would expect it to based on those values.

Comment: Your function will always return the value 2 - is that intentional?

Comment: And can you please show the code you are using to call the function, or at least the parts of that code that are setting up the parameters to the call.

Comment: @KresimirL., please do not suggest `goto` statement as a solution to a simple problem. it is something that a beginner should stay away from.

Comment: To your edit: _it touches "exit function" but then it just keeps going_ - this is a **recursive** function, which means that it calls itself. When it exits, it is returning to itself, on the next line after the recursive call. So its exiting from different levels (depending on how many times it called itself). It can be a hard concept to understand if you haven't used it before, but you have to create a very clear termination point, similar to the while statement: continue until a condition is true, and you have to propagate this condition throughout the calls

Comment: This could be replaced by a For loop (if you find it hard to follow), but you need to explain exactly how the _circular errors_ should be validated and dealt with. The easiest explanation for you would be to use your sample "before" data, and provide another sample of the "after" (expected) results and explain why it should work like that

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Before (Sheet1):

[image: Sheet1]

---

After (Review Sheet):

[image: ReviewSheet]

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestRecursion()

    Dim result As Variant, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheet1

    result = Recursion(ws.Cells(2, 8), ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(2, 5), 2, ws)

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function Recursion(ByVal whereItEnds As Long, lookingFor As Variant, _
                          ByRef currentMarker As Range, ByVal i As Long, _
                          ByRef wsEverything As Worksheet) As Long

    Dim col As Long, newMarker As String, currentMarker1 As Range

    newMarker = currentMarker.Value
    Recursion = 2
    col = 2

    If StrComp(lookingFor, newMarker, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit Function

    While Len(wsEverything.Cells(col, "B").Value2) > 0

        If StrComp(wsEverything.Cells(col, "B").Value2, newMarker, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

            wsEverything.Cells.Range("A" & col, "F" & col).Copy
            Worksheets("Review").Cells.Range("A" & i).PasteSpecial
            Worksheets("Review").Cells.Range("G" & i).Value = col
            i = i + 1

            Set currentMarker1 = wsEverything.Cells(col, "E")

            If col = whereItEnds Then Exit Function

            Recursion = Recursion(whereItEnds, lookingFor, currentMarker1, i, wsEverything)
        End If
        col = col + 1
    Wend
End Function
```

---

If so, you can provide more context explaining the logic for the expected result

Probably a less convoluted solution can be found for this

Comment: An expression of `(True)` will be equivalent to `True`, so the bracketing of expressions won't be an issue.  (Personally, I hate seeing them there, but it won't cause a problem.)